# Webpack Hot Module Replacement still requires full refresh even after setting up

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6

I got my webpack Hot Module Replacement working. I was told that once it is working, I would no longer have to do a full refresh for my code. This is not the case! I still require a refresh when I make changes to my code! (`App.js`).

How can I properly enable webpack HMR?

Link to the project on [github](https://github.com/liondancer/boothie)

This is my entry point

```
import './styles/index.css';
import App from './components/App';
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

const rootDOMNode = document.getElementById('app');

function renderRoot() {
  render(<App/>, rootDOMNode);
}
renderRoot();

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./components/App', () => {
    console.log('Accepting the updated module');
    renderRoot();
  });
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const path = require("path");
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require( "clean-webpack-plugin");
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    "./app/index"
  ],
  devtool: "inline-source-map",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"), // Note: Physical files are only output by the production build task `npm run build`.
    publicPath: "/",
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    hot: true,
    port: 3000,
    open: true,
    compress: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      disable: false,
      filename: "css/style.css",
      allChunks: true
    }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),

  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['env', 'react']
        }
      } },
      // { test: /(\.css)$/, use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"] },
      { test: /(\.css)$/, use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(["css-loader"]) },
      { test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/, use: ["file-loader"] },
      // for fonts
      { test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/, use: ["file-loader"] }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: I don't use React, but I do use HMR.  One thing you need to remember it's the calling side that needs to also be hot.  The best thing I've found is to make sure all units have the hot.accept.  There is a webpack plugin you can use to do this ->  https://github.com/loggur/webpack-module-hot-accept

Comment: add react-hot-loader that way React knows it needs to re render

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it is not working is because you have to re-require your `app` once you get the hot update, otherwise you are just re-rendering your original app.

the following code should work:

```
import './styles/index.css';
//import App from './components/App';
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

const rootDOMNode = document.getElementById('app');

let App;
function renderRoot() {
  App = require('./components/App').default; // we have to re-require this every time it changes otherwise we are rendering the same old app.
  render(<App/>, rootDOMNode);
}
renderRoot();

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./components/App', () => {
    console.log('Accepting the updated module');
    renderRoot();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use hot reloading with webpack-dev-server by adding a script in package.json.

```
webpack-dev-server --output-public-path=/dist/ --inline --hot
```